# How to render in a imGui Window

Tags: opengl, c++, glfw, imgui

I am learning OpenGL by glfw3 lib and I am using imgui to make a interesting application.
However, I can not render what I want in a imgui window.

I searched google and get below link:

1. [Render in a imGui Window](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/150214/render-in-a-imgui-window)
2. [How can I render an OpenGL scene into an ImGui window?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/140693/how-can-i-render-an-opengl-scene-into-an-imgui-window)

I tried about two days and I have rendered a triangle in a imgui window.
However, when I try to render content as this [link](https://learnopengl.com/video/getting-started/coordinate_system_depth.mp4)([Tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems) and [Code](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/6.2.coordinate_systems_depth/coordinate_systems_depth.cpp)) shows me.
The box in my imgui window will not spin! It is a stationary photo.
What's wrong with my code?

`#define __abc__`is a value to test.
Xhader.h just is the header file in the tutorial, also .vs and .fs files.
The only difference is the tutorial uses glad.h and I use glew.h.

```
#define __abc__
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stb_image.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include "imgui.h"
#include "imgui_impl_glfw.h"
#include "imgui_impl_opengl3.h"

#include "Xhader.h"



void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);

GLFWwindow* Proinit();
void imguiSetup(GLFWwindow* window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;


int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window = Proinit();
    imguiSetup(window);

    int view3d_width = 100;
    int view3d_height = 200;



    // configure global opengl state
    // -----------------------------
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // build and compile our shader zprogram
    // ------------------------------------
    Xhader ourShader("shader/vs.txt", "shader/fs.txt");

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float vertices[] = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

            -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    GLuint VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GLuint VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);


    //---------------------------------------    FBO    -----------------------------//
#ifdef __abc__
    unsigned int fbo;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

    GLuint TOF;
    glGenTextures(1, &TOF);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TOF);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 400, 300, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
#else
    ;
#endif


    // load and create a texture 
    // -------------------------
    unsigned int texture1, texture2;
    // texture 1
    // ---------
    glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    // set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true); // tell stb_image.h to flip loaded texture's on the y-axis.
    std::string s1 = "resources/textures/container.jpg";
    std::string s2 = "resources/textures/awesomeface.png";
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load(s1.c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);
    // texture 2
    // ---------
    glGenTextures(1, &texture2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
    // set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    data = stbi_load(s2.c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        // note that the awesomeface.png has transparency and thus an alpha channel, so make sure to tell OpenGL the data type is of GL_RGBA
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    // tell opengl for each sampler to which texture unit it belongs to (only has to be done once)
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ourShader.use();
    ourShader.setInt("texture1", 0);
    ourShader.setInt("texture2", 1);


    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

#ifdef __abc__
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, TOF, 0);
#endif
        if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
            std::cout << "FRAMEBUFFER SUCCESS" << std::endl;
            glViewport(0, 0, 400, 300);
            // render
            // ------
            glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // also clear the depth buffer now!
            // bind textures on corresponding texture units
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
            // activate shader
            ourShader.use();
            // create transformations
            glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f); // make sure to initialize matrix to identity matrix first
            glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
            glm::mat4 projection = glm::mat4(1.0f);
            float time = (float)glfwGetTime();
            std::cout << time << std::endl;
            model = glm::rotate(model,time , glm::vec3(0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

            view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));
            projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
            // retrieve the matrix uniform locations
            unsigned int modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.ID, "model");
            unsigned int viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.ID, "view");
            // pass them to the shaders (3 different ways)
            glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
            glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, &view[0][0]);
            // note: currently we set the projection matrix each frame, 
            //but since the projection matrix rarely changes it's often best practice 
            //to set it outside the main loop only once.
            ourShader.setMat4("projection", projection);
            // render box
            glBindVertexArray(VAO);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

#ifdef __abc__
            glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);   
#endif
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete!" << std::endl;
        }
#ifdef __abc__
        // Start the Dear ImGui frame
        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame();
        ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame();
        ImGui::NewFrame();
        bool View_3D = true;
        if (View_3D) {
            ImGui::Begin("3D View", &View_3D);
            view3d_height = ImGui::GetWindowSize().x;
            view3d_width = ImGui::GetWindowSize().y;
            ImVec2 pos = ImGui::GetCursorScreenPos();
            ImGui::GetWindowDrawList()->AddImage(
                (void*)TOF,
                ImVec2(ImGui::GetCursorScreenPos()),
                ImVec2(ImGui::GetCursorScreenPos().x + ImGui::GetWindowSize().x - 15,
                    ImGui::GetCursorScreenPos().y + ImGui::GetWindowSize().y - 35),
                ImVec2(0, 1),
                ImVec2(1, 0)
            );
            ImGui::End();
        }



        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);


        ImVec4 clear_color = ImVec4(0.45f, 0.55f, 0.60f, 1.00f);
        // render
        ImGui::Render();
        int display_w, display_h;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &display_w, &display_h);
        glViewport(0, 0, display_w, display_h);
        glClearColor(clear_color.x, clear_color.y, clear_color.z, clear_color.w);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());
#endif

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}


GLFWwindow* Proinit() {
//glfwSetErrorCallback(glfw_error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit()) return (GLFWwindow*)1;
#ifdef __APPLE__
    // GL 3.2 + GLSL 150
    const char* glsl_version = "#version 150";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // 3.2+ only
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);            // Required on Mac
#else
    const char* glsl_version = "#version 130";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // 3.2+ only
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);            // 3.0+ only
#endif
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "Shader3D", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) { std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl; glfwTerminate(); return (GLFWwindow*)-1; }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    //glfwSwapInterval(1); // Enable vsync
    //glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
#if defined(IMGUI_IMPL_OPENGL_LOADER_GLEW)
    bool err = glewInit() != GLEW_OK;
#elif defined(IMGUI_IMPL_OPENGL_LOADER_GLAD)
    bool err = gladLoadGL() == 0;
#else
    bool err = false;
#endif
    if (err) { fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize OpenGL loader!\n"); return (GLFWwindow*)1; }


    return window;
}



void imguiSetup(GLFWwindow* window) {
    // Setup Dear ImGui context  
    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO(); (void)io;
    //io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableKeyboard;     // Enable Keyboard Controls 
    //io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableGamepad;      // Enable Gamepad Controls  
    ImGui::StyleColorsDark();
    ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForOpenGL(window, true);         //Setup Platform bindings
#ifdef __APPLE__
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init("#version 150");             //Setup Renderer bindings
#else
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init("#version 130");
#endif

}
```

Comment: Does it spin if you render directly to the default framebuffer?

Comment: yes, it spin if you use default buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Move these lines inside the while loop.

```
unsigned int fbo;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

GLuint TOF;
glGenTextures(1, &TOF);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TOF);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 400, 300, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Then once all your rendering is done you have to delete the frame buffer and texture object every time inside the loop.

```
glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glDeleteTextures(1, &TOF);
```

The idea is for each and every time inside the loop, the frame buffer needs to be created, utilized and the deleted. Other wise the buffer will not refresh.